# Automatic HTTPRedirect in Django view if user is authenticated?

Tags: django, django-models

I have successfully made it so the user must log in to view their profile, however, I only want the user to be able to view their profile and no one else.

Previously, they could visit`www.websitename.com/user/admin`
as well as `www.websitename.com/user/test` and it would bring up the data for the profile each time of the logged in user.

The URL to visit is `www.websitename.com/user/usernameofcurrentuser`

## Profile Page View

```
def profile_page(request, username):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    if request.user == username:
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            user = User.objects.get(username=username)
            taskitems = request.user.taskitem_set.all()
            return render_to_response('profile.html', {}, context)
        else:
            return render_to_response('login.html', {}, context)
    else:
        return render_to_response('login.html', {}, context)
```

However, even though the user is logged in, it's redirecting them to the sign in page. I know the user is logged in because it prints their name on the login page, yet it's not redirecting them to the profile associated with the username.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this :

```
def profile_page(request, username):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        if request.user.username == username:
            # removed user since already in request.user and available in template as 'user'
            # removed taskitems since directly available in template as 'user.taskitem_set.all'
            return render(request, 'profile.html')
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('profile_page', args=(request.user.username,)))
    else:
        return render(request, 'login.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `username` parameter since each user should only view their own profile. You can also use the `login_required` decorator to remove the extra conditional:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import render

@login_required
def profile_page(request):
    return render(request, 'profile.html')
```

Make sure to set `LOGIN_URL` in your `settings.py` so unauthenticated users get redirected to the right spot.